# Is it true that if $a, b, x, y>0$, $a+b \ge x+y$ and $ab \le xy$ then $a^n+b^n≥x^n+y^n$ for $n>1$?

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, x, y>0$, $a+b \ge x+y$ and $ab \le xy$ then $a^n+b^n \ge x^n+y^n$ where $n=2$.

> > *Is it true that if $a, b, x, y>0$, $a+b \ge x+y$ and $ab \le xy$ then $a^n+b^n \ge x^n+y^n$ for $n \ge 1$?*

I have just been checked it is true with $1< a, b, x, y \le 1000$ with $n=3,4$ by my computer. I am looking for a proof if this is true inequality.

Comment: Are we assuming $a, b, x, y \in \Bbb Z^+$?  Or can they be any positive reals?

Comment: fix $a,b.$ If $x+y<a+b$, then you can add an equal $\epsilon$ to each of $a,b$ and you will get a tighter inequality. That is, if your assertion is true, then it suffices to prove in the case when $a+b = x+y.$ Consider:
$$(x-y)^2 = (x+y)^2 - 4xy = (a+b)^2 - 4xy\leq (a+b)^2-4ab = (a-b)^2,$$
meaning $|x-y|\leq|a-b|.$ Now it's a fairly standard idea to prove that $x^n+y^n$ increases as they become "farther" apart if their sum is held constant - I forgot what it's called in the literature, but this is an easy induction.

Comment: Note:  I edited the header so that it matches the question in the body of the post.  The old header question was clearly false, so I suppose you intended the one in the body.  If I inadvertently changed your meaning, feel free to rollback the edit.

Comment: Thanks to every friend for help

Answer (score 4):

Let
$d_n
= a^n+b^n
$
and let $a+b=d$.

$\begin{array}\\
d_n(a+b)
&=(a^n+b^n)(a+b)\\
&=a^{n+1}+ba^n+ab^n+b^{n+1}\\
&=a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}+ab(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})\\
&=d_{n+1}+abd_{n-1}\\
\text{so}\\
d_{n+1}
&=d_n(a+b)-abd_{n-1}\\
&=dd_n-abd_{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Similarly,
if
$e_n=x^n+y^n
$
and
$e=x+y$,
$e_{n+1}
=ee_n-xye_{n-1}
$.

$d_1 \ge e_1$
and

$\begin{array}\\
d_2
&=a^2+b^2\\
&=a^2+2ab+b^2-2ab\\
&=(a+b)^2-2ab\\
&\ge(x+y)^2-2xy\\
&=e_2\\
\end{array}
$

If
$d_n \ge e_n$
and
$d_{n-1} \ge e_{n-1}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
d_{n+1}
&=dd_n-abd_{n-1}\\
&\ge ee_n-xyd_{n-1}
\qquad d\ge e, xy\ge ab, d_n\ge e_n\\
&= ee_n-xy(e_{n-1}-e_{n-1}+d_{n-1})\\
&= ee_n-xye_{n-1}-xy(e_{n-1}-d_{n-1})\\
&= e_{n+1}+xy(d_{n-1}-e_{n-1})\\
&\ge e_{n+1}
\qquad d_{n-1}\ge e_{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$d_n \ge e_n$
for all $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the inequality holds for $n - 1$ and $n - 2$, we can use induction.
\begin{align}
a^n + b^n &= a^{n - 1}(a + b) - a^{n - 1}b + b^{n - 1}(a + b) - ab^{n - 1} \\
&=(a + b)(a^{n - 1} + b^{n - 1}) - ab(a^{n - 2} + b^{n - 2}) \\
&\geq (x + y)(x^{n - 1} + y^{n - 1}) - xy(a^{n - 2} + b^{n - 2}) \\
&= x^n + y^n + xy(x^{n - 2} + y^{n - 2} - a^{n - 2} - b^{n - 2}) \\
&> x^n + y^n
\end{align}
Indeed, when $n = 1$ we are given the inequality. When $n = 2$, we have
\begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 &= (a + b)^2 - 2ab \\
&\geq (x + y)^2 - 2xy \\
&=x^2 + y^2.
\end{align}
Let me know if there are any mistakes.

Comment: Nice variation on my answer. upvoted